# Service injection into controller having in seperate files with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

When i try to inject service into controller which I have in separate file mentioned in below code i get error:

> TypeError: myService.getData is not a function
>       at new  (controllers.js:18)
>       at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:39)
>       at M.instance (angular.min.js:80)
>       at D (angular.min.js:61)
>       at g (angular.min.js:55)
>       at g (angular.min.js:55)
>       at angular.min.js:54
>       at angular.min.js:20
>       at r.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
>       at r.$apply (angular.min.js:134)

### index.html

load all js files in this html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/all.css">
  <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/service.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/myApp.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the main file where we load controllers and services at once

### myApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.service', 'app.controllers']);
```

### service.js

here i tried to get data from server and wants to use in controller

```
var app = angular.module("app.service", []);

app.service('myService', function($http) {
  function getData (callbackFunc) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "url"
      }).success(function(data){
        callbackFunc(data);
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
  }
});
```

### controllers.js

This file include all logic and inject myService from service.js file.
i use myService from service.js and tried to get data, but i got an error all the time

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.service'])

  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'myService',

    function ($scope, $http, $timeout, myService) {

   myService.getData(function(dataResponse) {

          $scope.surveys = dataResponse;

});

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service module declaration has problem.

You are getting module name without declaring it.

Try like this

```
var appSvc=angular.module("app.service",[]);

appSvc.service('myService', function($http){});
```

bind Your method with this

Like this

```
this.getData =function (callbackFunc) {}
```

Comment: When i use these code i got an error:                                                  TypeError: myService.getData is not a function

Comment: TypeError: myService.getData is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:18)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.min.js:39)
    at M.instance (angular.min.js:80)
    at D (angular.min.js:61)
    at g (angular.min.js:55)
    at g (angular.min.js:55)
    at angular.min.js:54
    at angular.min.js:20
    at r.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
    at r.$apply (angular.min.js:134)

Comment: @tusharbalar that's because getData should be declared as `this.getData = function(callbackFunc) { ... }`. I also suggest you read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/, because you're using a promise anti-pattern here.

Comment: yeah @JBNizet is right . if you use service you have to use `this` , if you use factory your have to return your object.